# Tomcat: Changes made to tomcat-users.xml got undone

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, tomcat7

I am faching this very strange problem.
On my OpenSuse Linux environment, I have edited the following file in order to get my ant script working for Tomcat7:

```
/TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

I have edited the following:

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>

<user username="tomcat" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, manager-script"/>
```

The strange part is I have made these some days ago, and I cannot see these changes in the above mentioned file.

Do these changes get undone when the machine/tomcat restarts?

My ant script seems to be working fine still, if the above changes get undone then why is that the ant script still running.

Yes, I have looked into the file as a root user as well.

any idea, what is happenng here?

Comment: This is not running on a VM or EC2 or something is it?

Comment: @ScaryWombat on vm VirtualBox

Comment: Is the state of the vm being saved when shutdown?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I would say so, as everything is getting saved.